# Is it possible to correct [flip] this P-Trap?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, sink, p-trap

[image]

So I've realized this bathroom sink p-trap was installed incorrectly, but based on the geometry, I cannot flip it to the way it's supposed to flow...

I even hacksawed the vertical pipe [grey] connected to sink basin in hopes that the white, flexible connector could go higher up...

Suggestions? My only thought is to get an entirely new cabinet that sits higher so it can properly drain and we can avoid the smells...

I assume if I buy a couple different parts, I may be able to save some money for time being, but not sure what configuration would allow for optimal flow.

Thanks!

Comment: Do whatever is necessary to get rid of that white accordion pipe. Unless, of course, you enjoy cleaning out drain clogs.

Answer (score 2):

I would put a 90 elbow on the waste sticking out from the wall and the long horizontal black pipe into that. If necessary extend that out from the wall as needed.

Then adjust the horizontal length so that the P entry sit directly under the grey pipe and extend the grey pipe down.

And, as per the comment, get rid of that (horrible) accordion - all it does is collect cr*p and slow the flow.
And when I said a 90 elbow, get a swept one ie it has a nice curve not a sharp 90...

Like this, but you have to imagine the grey extended down, and the 90 elbow as well:
[image]

Comment: And get rid of the white accordion

Comment: thank you for quick response! @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. --- so the 90 out from the waste would ben d toward the grey pipe, not downward correct? so then i could insert straight part of black horz pipe into that, and the bended part into small end of ptrap - in that picture, there is a small 90 going into waste

Comment: @tsuga see edit.

Comment: Just follow the picture. Only thing is you might need (hard to tell from the picture) to extend the pipe from the wall a couple of inches in order to be far enough past the water valve to allow access to the water valve.

Comment: Exactly correct. Also realize that you can rotate the trap parts as needed to get things to line up, or get clearance, so long as you maintain this relationship (so if the P needs to come forward a bit to clear the valve handles, that's just a rotation towards the camera, the outlet pipe would then rotate to meet the drain elbow, etc. And the line out of the trap towards the drain should slope down at 1/4" per foot, or 2mm/10cm as you prefer.